# HP CM2320 Printer crashes windows 2003 spooler in TS/Citrix

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server, printing, hp, citrix

I'm having a very annoying issue with an HP printer (CM2320): all of a sudden, any user who has that printer installed locally as default printer would crash any Windows 2003 terminal services or Citrix server (XenApp PS 4.5) as soon as he connect, causing the session to hang and other users to be unable to connect to the server.

To restore functionality, an administrator has to connect to the server's console session and acknowledge the error message about spoolsv.exe having crashed with an AV.

I tried downloading the latest drivers from HP (an adventure worthy of Lara Croft in itself) and install it on all servers but that didn't seem to have helped the situation: the spooler is still crashing.

Anyone has a suggestion about what I could do about this ?

Comment: Hey - don't forget to mark an answer for this and your older questions too. That's how this site works.

Comment: I always mark answers as such if they are answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to define a printer mapping in Citrix/TS to use a different driver for that model. That printer appears to have HP Universal Print Driver support, so try that.

In fact, this document tells you to do that. 
https://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/10498-102-647377/Citrix%20Supported%20HP%20Printers.pdf

Comment: Thanks. The document actually tells me that this printer is supported under 2003 with driver version 61.072.42.00 and that the HP-UDP should be used for 2008/7.

Comment: Whoops -correct, for PCL. I zoomed right to the PS column, which says "UPD." So, it depends on your environment, the docs you print, and which (PS vs PCL) works better for you.

Comment: I'd say that, what works for me is anything that doesn't crash the spooler. Users, however, tends to use PCL5/6.

Comment: I've forced the users to use the Citrix UPD and it solved the issue. I'm now busy trying to find out all the various names that this printer's drivers use.

Comment: Yup - welcome to Citrix(TS) printing. Trust me, it was worse under Metaframe 1.8. You kids today, you have no idea how easy you've got it. If that balls goes over my fence, you're not getting it back.

Answer (score 0):

We've got 4 of these HP CM2320nf's on one of our 2003 x64 terminal servers. We're running the latest HP Universal Print Driver PCL6 with success. Would just suggest you just do a clean up of older HP print drivers from the server before you install, and check your AV software isn't scanning the print spooler dirs ([more info here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX114522)).